# Jquery form validator: Unexpected identifier

Tags: jquery

I am working with a basic jquery form validator for learning purposes. Every time I run the page in my browser I get back an `Unexpected Identifier` error. I have checked several times the code to see if it was a quotation issue but no luck. How can I get rid of that error? [LIVE DEMO](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/validator/index.php)

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function() {
        var abort = false;
        $("div.error").remove();
        $(":input[required]").each(function(){
           if ($(this).val() === ""){
               $(this).after("<div class=\"error\"> This is a required field </div>");
               abort = true;
           }  
        });
        if (abort){return false;} else {
            postData = $("#myform").serialize();
            $.post("process.php", postData+"&action=submit&ajaxrequest=1", function(msg){
                if(msg){
                    $("#myform").before(msg);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});

$("input[placeholder]").blur(function(){
   $("div.error").remove();
   var myPattern = $(this).attr("pattern");
   var myPlaceholder = $(this).attr("placeholder");
   var isValid = $(this).val().search(myPattern) >= 0;

   if (!isValid){
       $(this).focus();
       $(this).after("<div class=\"error\">The entered data does not match expected pattern: " + myPlaceholder + "</div>");
   } //isValid test
}); // onblur
```

[image]

Comment: which line does it give the error on?

Comment: is the error appearing on page load or on a an action performed like click

Comment: @badZoke line 16 of my `script.js` i get the error.

Comment: @ArunPJohny after the button click

Comment: what is line 16 in the file

Comment: `msg` is undefined in the code you've provided.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Line 16: `$("#myform").before(msg);`

Comment: Comment that line and check what does message contain

Comment: what is the content of `msg`

Comment: Try with different Jquery Library ..!!

Comment: @badZoke I added a link to a test site for better details.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I added a link to a test site for better details.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I added a link to a test site for better details.

Answer (score 0):

**postData** should be declared with var, but that's not the problem. You almost certainly have incorrectly placed { } or ;

I think the blur function also be inside the `$(document).ready(function() { block?`, because its possible jQuery isn't operational till then

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting all code inside **Doc ready function**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myform").submit(function() {
       //......all the code stuff here
   });

   $("input[placeholder]").blur(function(){
       //......all the code stuff here
   });
}); // end of doc ready
```